# Start the same instance of application from background

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I know this question was asked many times before but I can't find the answer yet
How can I start app2 from another app1 and if app2 is already running get it from background

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an **implicit** `intent` to start app2 - it'll work just as you want it (it'll be resumed if already running in background or started from scratch if not running).

If you're using an **explicit** `intent` - it depends whether the specific `Activity` you're calling is in the top of the task stack or not. Here it can get a bit more complicated if this `Activity` has some `launchMode` specified, but won't get into details, as I'm assuming you know it if you'll be calling it explicitly.

Comment: I get the intent from
    ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_name);
it returns launch intent for the app as I don't know in which intent the app is running

Comment: This method returns an explicit Intent for the app, so the second rule applies to you.

Comment: Yes I know I want to start the same instance but I don't know how